# Create click event programmatically for link button in each accordion pane

Tags: asp.net, accordion

I have created an Accordion dynamically and added AccordionPanes through backend with respective controls and data click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085993/using-ajax-accordion-with-repeater) to view my problem and how I solved it. I have added a link button in each AccordionPane but now I want to add a click event so that I can access data in that specific pane and I need to use functions to populate data.

I create my controls in the page_init event.

How can I go about doing this?

I have come across a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867441/add-an-onclick-event-to-a-dynamically-created-linkbutton) that is almost the same as what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by adding the event handlers with Javascript Like this:

```
function pageLoad()
{
    var accordionControl = $find('Accordion1_AccordionExtender');
    accordionControl.add_selectedIndexChanging(PaneChanging);
    accordionControl.add_selectedIndexChanged(PaneChanged);
}

function PaneChanged(sender, args)
{
    alert('In Changed handler.');
}

function PaneChanging(sender, args)
{
    alert('In Changing hanlder.');
}
```

A similar question has been posted [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1259392/2349722.aspx)

The specific control you would be looking for is:

```
$addHandler(header, "click", acc._headerClickHandler);
```

Comment: ,I have add an attribute to my link button that will do a post back and call a vb function but does not seems to work.
lnkCopy.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
          lnkCopy.Attributes.Add("href", "javascript:__doPostBack('sbGetData','" & dt.Rows(i).Item("PRENR").ToString & "')")

Comment: Try debugging with the following: cmdMyButton.attributes.add("onclick", "alert('hello');")